# How to compare words in two lists and extract the matching words as separate list using python

Tags: python, list, nlp

I have a dataframe with three columns, format shown below.

```
ticket_subject                     keys                      automation     
[mouse,is not, working]          [hardware, change]             70%
[password, wrong]                [error, password]              50%
[reset, password]                [account, lock]                50%
[forgot, userid]                 [userid, forgot]               50%
```

...
...

columns "ticket_subject" and "keys" have list in each rows of the dataframe.
what i want is, take the first list from "keys" column, check all the words from "keys" is present in any of the rows of "ticket_subject" column. if it matches with any of the rows in "ticket_subject" column then make a separate column with those words.

order of words doesn't matter in this case (e.g. [account,lock] need not to be present in the same order. just to check if these two presents in any  of the row). likewise, i need to check each row of "keys" column with "ticket_subject" column and create a new column with the matching words.

if its just two list comparison, i am able to do. but, since its two columns with lists of words, am struggling to proceed.

I need your help on this

```
 expected_output_column

 []
 [password]
 []
 [userid, forgot]
 ....
 ...
```

Comment: If you find a match between `[password, wrong]` and `[error, password]` what should the new list contain? `[password, wrong, error, password]`?

Comment: With any of the rows in `ticket_subject`?

Comment: It seems that you need a `set` of all the words that appear anywhere in `ticket_subject`.  Then intersect that with the `keys` list; the result is the value of your new column.

Comment: Nick, it should contain [password]

Comment: Daniel, yes any rows in ticket_subject

Comment: Prune, can you please share the code..as am learning python and implementing in my project

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe for thid example